# In PackageDiscoveryTrait.php line 366:

Tags: laravel, composer-php

How to solve this?

[image: 1]

I want to install package dompdf in my laravel, but i get error in composer

Comment: Please share more details, like the error message in text form and your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

first navigate to your laravel project
use these commands:

Composer install

composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).